# Upgrade a Laravel 4.2 project to Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have project written in Laravel 4.2 that works fine, but I have to improve it by adding some functionality. I want to use Laravel 5.1 for this. Is there any way to automatically convert a Laravel 4.2 project into Laravel 5.1?

Comment: No: http://laravel.com/docs/master/upgrade

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly not, it's quite a big change so you'll have to follow their upgrade guide:
http://laravel.com/docs/master/upgrade#upgrade-5.0.
Look for **Upgrading To 5.0 From 4.2**

Comment: And even then, there are some changes (minor ones by comparison) between Laravel 5.0 and Laravel 5.1 that will need to be addressed.